# Workspace integrity, couldn't load project. After upgrading to MACOS Catalina

Tags: xcode, react-native, macos-catalina, xcode10

Please need a help, I just upgraded macos to catalina, after that I updated xcode to 11.5, i also have xcode 10.1. Now my older project when opened with xcode 10.1 the below screenshot error is getting. I updated my cocoapod also. Still it remains.[check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qALth.png)

Comment: Check if the path is correct. If you install / update cocoapods see if it give any errors or suggestions. You can use $(inherited) in your path.

Answer (score 23):

Finally i got the solution goto **System Preference**s <  **Security & Privacy** < **Privacy** < **Full Disk Access** click the lock icon to unlock and **add xcode enable it**

Comment: you are the goat

Comment: still not working for me :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for several months and finally I identified that (in my case) the issue was caused by some sort of file corruption when migrating SwiftDat from Pod to SwiftPackage....

The project compiled and run fine, but we could not get rid of the ugly "Workspace integrity, couldn't load project" error.

I was able to fix it doing the following:

- Removed the **SwiftDate** SwiftPackage v6.3.1
- Installed the same version using PODs and compiled the project without the error.
- Reverting back to use the SwiftPackage made the trick.....

Comment: Probably related to this issue: https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate/issues/791